# @property (copy) vs method [ copy]

Tags: objective-c

Is there any difference between (A) and (B) below?
(Assume NON ARC, if it matters)

```
// --- (A) ---
@interface Zoo : NSObject{}
@property (copy) Dog *dog;
@end
//..... then somewhere
someZoo.dog = another_dog;
```

```
// --- (B) ---
@interface Zoo : NSObject{}
@property (assign) Dog *dog;
@end
//..... then somewhere
someZoo.dog = [another_dog copy];
```

If the answer is negative, is there any advantage of using (A)?
I find approach (B) less error prone, since the explicit code shows exactly what is going on, but I'm not expert, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming non-ARC:

Approach A is correct: you have a strong property with copy, Zoo retains the instance of Dog upon assignment, it should also release it in `dealloc`. This ensures correct memory management: `copy` returns retain count = 1, in `dealloc` it returns to 0 and the instance of Dog is deallocated.

Approach B is incorrect. Although, it will work in this case, it's ultimately wrong. The Zoo object needs to decide whether to retain the instance of dog or not. In your case the retain count of Dog is controlled outside of Zoo class - ultimately against the principle (see below). This leads to several potential problems.

1. Memory leak if the Zoo object does't release the `dog` in dealloc. In fact, according to conventions, it shouldn't because the property is declared with 'assign' attribute.
2. Crash due to dead instance in case somewhere else in the code somewhere uses assignment like:

`someZoo.dog = another_dog`

The first access to the `dog` property inside Zoo will crash, since Zoo hasn't retained the `dog`, which might be released elsewhere.

You need to decide whether the Zoo class needs to retain an instance of dog or not. Normally the answer would be 'yes', except for the cases when it leads to retain loops. Since the Zoo owns the dog, the Zoo must have a strong (retain or copy) relationship, but the Dog must keep `assign` back to the Zoo.

Naturally, if Zoo uses `retain` or `copy` attribute for the property it must release it in dealloc. The Dog must not retain or release the Zoo ever.

Also, the principle is simple: The object that receives an instance decides whether to retain it or not. If it retains that instance, it must release it eventually.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between A and B is that in B you have to remember to use `copy` everywhere you assign `dog`, whereas with A takes care of that for you. B is more fragile.

And the other consideration is that with A, you can glance at the interface and understand the memory semantics, whereas with B, you have to pour through the whole implementation of `Zoo` to deduce what’s going on.

And, of course, as Davyd points out (+1), you wouldn’t use `assign`. It should be `copy` if using copy semantics or `retain` if not.